# Maven verify ClassNotFoundException for class of Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I try to run verify lifecycle of Maven for my Java Spring Boot project. It compiles fine using `mvn spring-boot:run` but when I run `mvn clean verify` it fails thus:

```
$mvn clean verify -Dsurefire.skip=true -X
...
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.209 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.fitforger.FitForgerBackendApplicationTests
    initializationError(com.fitforger.FitForgerBackendApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fitforger/model/GymRat
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fitforger.model.GymRat
```

where `com.fitforger.model.GymRat` is one of the classes of my application.

Project structure:

```
+----src
     +----main
     |    +----java
     |    |    +----com
     |    |         +----fitforger
     |    |              +----controller
     |    |              |    +----GymRatController.java
     |    |              |    +----WorkoutNodeController.java
     |    |              +----dao
     |    |              |    +----GymRatDAO.java
     |    |              +----exception
     |    |              |    +----GymRatCreationFailure.java
     |    |              |    +----GymRatExistsException.java
     |    |              |    +----GymRatNotFound.java
     |    |              |    +----GymRatUpdateFailure.java
     |    |              +----FitForgerBackendApplication.java
     |    |              +----model
     |    |              |    +----FitForgerModel.java
     |    |              |    +----GymRat.java
     |    |              |    +----WorkoutAttribute.java
     |    |              |    +----WorkoutNode.java
     |    |              |    +----WorkoutNodeTypes.java
     |    |              +----repository
     |    |                   +----CouchbaseRepository.java
     |    |                   +----FitForgerRepository.java
     |    +----resources
     |         +----application.properties
     +----test
          +----java
          |    +----com
          |         +----fitforger
          |              +----FitForgerBackendApplicationTests.java
          |              +----GymRatSteps.java
          |              +----repository
          |                   +----CouchbaseRepositoryTest.java
          +----resources
               +----com
                    +----fitforger
                         +----GymRat.feature
```

Relevant bits of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com.fitforger.FitForgerBackendApplicationTests</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <skip>${surefire.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com.fitforger.FitForgerBackendApplicationTests</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build
```

Comment: This(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254) looks to be similar to what you are facing. Could you try with `<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>`

Comment: This worked!  Thanks much...might want to add a general response so i can mark it as correct.

Comment: glad it worked. I have moved it as answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OP problem solved by doing below,

[This](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254) looks to be similar to what you are facing. Could you try with

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 9):

This problem can also manifest as a failure of integration test cases to find your `application.properties` resource.

This happens [because](https://sandor-nemeth.github.io/2017/10/16/integration-tests-with-spring-boot-classnotfoundexception.html) of the interaction of the Spring Boot repackaging, done by the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, and the logic that the `maven-failsafe-plugin` uses to set up the classpath for integration tests.

The Failsafe plugin [puts](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html) the packaged JAR on the classpath, rather than the directory holding the unpacked classes and resources (as given by the `project.build.outputDirectory` property, which is usually `${basedir}/target/classes`). However, the repackaging done by `spring-boot-maven-plugin` places the classes and resources of your application in an unusual location in the JAR, so although Failsafe examines the JAR, it does not find what it is looking for.

You can work around this problem by explicitly telling the Failsafe plugin to put the directory holding the unpacked classes and resources on using classpath, by using `additionalClasspathElements` in its configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <additionalClasspathElements>
                <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/target/classes</additionalClasspathElement>
            </additionalClasspathElements>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are not extending `spring-boot-starter-parent`, you have to add `classesDirectory` in your failsafe config (just as [spring-boot-starter-parent](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7ed64f0677709e460fbcbc19539487d8f7e59965/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml#L93) pom does):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- this one here! -->
        <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*Found in a [JIRA comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1198?focusedCommentId=16674086&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16674086) on a similar issue ([failsafe 2.19+ not working with spring boot 1.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#integration-tests-with-the-maven-failsafe-plugin)).*