# Cobertura+Failsafe: make "mvn clean site" proceed even if an integration test fails

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-failsafe-plugin, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have a Java8/Maven/Spring Boot project involving the `maven-failsafe-plugin` (in order to run integration tests in `*IT.java`, separately from unit tests in `*Test.java`) and `cobertura-maven-plugin`.

The issue is that `mvn clean site` fails to conclude if an integration test fails, while `mvn clean site` is fine if an unit test fails.

To reproduce this, I first added a `src/test/java/app/FailingTest.java` containing:

```
package app;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class FailingTest {

    @Test
    public void failingTest () {
        fail();
    }
}
```

and `mvn clean site` yields:

```
...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running app.FailingTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.063 s <<< FAILURE! - in app.FailingTest
[ERROR] failingTest(app.FailingTest)  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
    at app.FailingTest.failingTest(FailingTest.java:11)
...
[INFO] Cobertura Report generation was successful.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I renamed that class to `src/test/java/app/FailingIT.java`, and `mvn clean site` yields:

```
...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running app.FailingIT
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.031 s <<< FAILURE! - in app.FailingIT
[ERROR] failingTest(app.FailingIT)  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
    at app.FailingIT.failingTest(FailingIT.java:11)
...
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.1:verify (default) @ example-project ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can one fix this?

My `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>example-project</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.16.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- This is needed for the failsafe plugin, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42128153/9164010 -->
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- This is needed to avoid a compilation error, cf. below -->
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- This is needed to avoid a compilation error, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50661649/9164010 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <!-- This is needed to avoid a compilation error, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099913/9164010 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the [`maven-failsafe-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) that's responsible for the build failure. The reason is clearly called out in your `pom.xml` as :

```
<goal>integration-test</goal>
```

If the test is really an Integration Test (*IT*), you must fix it or else if it is not an integration test, you can rename it to be categorized as a Unit Test(*UT*) but still fix it :)

Another poor way of getting rid of this error could be commenting out the failsafe plugin declaration all together in the `pom.xml` making it inactive. I would suggest to refrain from doing so though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it does not really addresses my question: I would like that `mvn verify` fails due to the `integration-test` goal, but `mvn site` proceeds to generate coverage stats for unit tests and/or integration tests, even if an integration test fails. Basically, there seems to be some "asymmetry" between cobertura+surefire and cobertura+failsafe regarding the "exit status" of unit tests and integration tests. Is it possible to fix this? (unfortunately this case doesn't seem to be covered in the failsafe and cobertura documentation)

Comment: @ErikMD Are you looking out for something [like skipping tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html)? Also to question the basic, why do you need the failsafe plugin for then?

Comment: I use the failsafe plugin to run integration tests with `mvn verify`. I've seen examples on the web showing that surefire can also be configured to run integration tests, but the [failsafe doc](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) says it's better to use failsafe than surefire for that purpose. I don't really want to skip tests, I just want `mvn site` not to fail if an integration test fails (in the same way as currently, `mvn site` does not fail if an unit test fails), to get unit+integration tests cobertura reports. It'd be great to know solutions to achieve this.